# POST - 500 (internal server error )

Tags: php, jquery, post, ssl

In my case I am sending **POST** request by `$.post` using JQuery and PHP.

But I am gettinh this error in while posting data.

**POST https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/php/control/LoginControl.php 500 (Internal Server Error)**

here is my jquery code :

```
var url = 'php/control/LoginControl.php';
        $.post(url,
    {
                task : "login_verify",
                username:_username ,
                password:_user_password,
    })
        .error(function(er){
            console.log(er);
        })
        .success(
                function(data){
                    if(data == true){
                        window.location = 'index.php';
                    }else{
                        $("#user_password" ).css({border:'1px solid red'});
                    }
                }
        );
```

PHP - LoginControl.php

```
<?php 
try{
    if(isset($_POST) && $_POST['task'] == 'login_verify'){
        $user_name = $_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);

        require '../class/login.php';
        if(class_exists('Login')){
            $user = Login::verifyCredentials($user_name,$password);
            if($user != NULL){
                if(isset($_SESSION)){
                    session_destroy();
                }
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['uid'] = $user[0]->ADMIN_ID;
                echo true;
            }else{
                echo false;
            }
        }
    }
}  catch (Exception $ex){
    echo $ex;
}
?>
```

**note:** I deploy successfully this code on live test server. and it is completely working fine. But on new server I am getting this error. I am using **SSL** on this new server this might be issue.

Please comment if its not enough information. 
Please help.

Comment: 500 indicates an error on your server. Look at the server error logs - they will tell you what is going on.

Comment: @Hobo sapiens - Thanks you very much for response. Actually we are using shared server and I don't have configuration access of this server. so I have to ask my client for this. Is there anything I can do by my code or you have any reference about this error so I can ask client to get access ??

Comment: By default, $.post() expects a json response back. I'd suggest adding the return info you want the LoginControl.php file to return, and echo a json_encode of that array. That's how I normally do it.

--source: I've run into this issue many, many times.

Comment: yes Kaleb klein I totally agree with you. But I when I debug I thinks PHP file is not even executing. I can not get response of "  echo 'hi';  ". but when I manully run this file not by ajaz but by inserting URL in browser. I can see "hi". So I think this is something wromg with POST or I don't know.

Comment: I posted an answer with edits and a little explanation that could be your issue. Maybe that'll help

Answer (score 0):

Here's an edit to your scripts. Maybe something along the lines of this will help.

JS:

```
 $(function()
 {
    var url = 'php/control/LoginControl.php';
    $.post(url, {
        task: "login_verify",
        username: _username,
        password: _password
    }, function(data, status, xhr)
    {
        // success
        if(data.error===false)
            window.location = 'index.php';
        else
            $("#user_password").css({border: '1px solid #ff0000'});
    }).error(function(xhr, status, error)
    {
        console.log("Error loading page. Status: "+status+" | Error: "+error);
    });
 });
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
 // Session must be started before session checking and destroying can happen
 session_start();

 // Set error true by default
 // Error is always returned.
 // If no error, it'll be set to false in if statement
 // So a value will always be returned.
 $return['error'] = true;

 if(isset($_POST) && $_POST['task'] == 'login_verify')
 {
    require_once __DIR__.'/../class.login.php';
    if(class_exists('Login'))
    {
        $uname = $_POST['username'];
        $passwd = $_POST['password'];
        $user = Login::verifyCredentials($uname, $passwd);
        if(!empty($user))
        {
            if(isset($_SESSION))
                session_destroy();

            $_SESSION['uid'] = $user[0]->ADMIN_ID;
        }
        else
            $return['error'] = false;
    }
 }

 echo @json_encode($return);
```

One thing I did notice in your PHP script that I corrected in my edits, is you're using $_SESSION and session_destroy() when no session is open. You must first define session_start() before any of the session methods or magic variables become available to you. That's why I placed it at the very top of the PHP script.

Also, if you want to use another data type rather than json, it's easiest just to use the $.ajax() function

```
 var loginData = {
    username: _username,
    password: _password,
    task: 'login_verify'
 };

 $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    data: loginData,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data, status, xhr)
    {
        // If page loading was a success. i.e. 200 OK status message
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error)
    {
        // error. Status other than 200
    }
 });
```

======================================================================
EDIT: New Code
Take a look at this, see if this will help.

PHP:

```
 <?php
 $return['error'] = true;

 if(isset($_POST) && $_POST['task'] == 'login_verify')
 {
    if(!empty($_POST['formData']['username']))
    {
        if(!empty($_POST['formData']['password']))
        {
            $return['error'] = false;
            $message = "The AJAX call was successfull! The data passed is listed below.\n\n"
                . "task: " . $_POST['task'] . "\n"
                . "username: " . $_POST['formData']['username'] . "\n"
                . "password: " . $_POST['formData']['password'];

            $return['message'] = $message;
        }
        else
            $return['message'] = 'Password is empty!';
    }
    else
        $return['message'] = 'Username is empty!';
 }
 else
 {
    $return['message'] = 'Invalid request! ' . $json->task;
 }

 echo @json_encode($return);
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(function()
 {
    $("#login").click(function()
    {
        var jdata = {
            task: 'login_verify',
            formData: {
                username: $("#username").val(),
                password: $("#password").val()
            }
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'login.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: jdata,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data, status, xhr)
            {
                var dataStatus = (data.error===true) ? "Error" : "Success";
                var message = "Status: " + dataStatus + "\n"
                    + data.message;

                alert(message);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error)
            {
                alert('Error: ' + error);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
 });
```

This code, works. I have a live version of it. Exact code and all.
[AJAX/PHP Example](http://testsites.kalebklein.com/ajaxtest/)

I hope this helps

Comment: no its not working. Getting the same error.    **Error loading page. Status: error | Error: Internal Server Error **

Comment: I've updated the answer with new code and a link to a live working demo. The demo uses the same JS/PHP code as pasted above. If you're able to incorporate this into your own code, then it's something more. Maybe something is going wrong with the login class and you may have to test it out w/o ajax to pinpoint the issue more easily.